# redirecting static pages to dynamic while using the static filename to query

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

People who have bookmarked for example

```
http://www.dogs.bark/breeds.cfm/12700_female_rottweiler.htm
```

or

```
http://www.dogs.bark/whatevertext/12700_female_rottweiler.htm
(use female + rottweiler)
```

Direct this to:

```
http://www.dogs.bark/search/result/?q=female+rottweiler
```

So basically it should take the last words (can be multiple) that are separated with underscores as keywords

I understand this should be done using mod.rewrite but that's about it. I find it hard to understand how mod rewrite works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/.*?/[0-9]+_(.*)\.html?$ /search/result/?q=$1
```

Remove the `301` if you  don'twant it to be a permanent redirect. You can also use mod_rewrite, it'll look pretty much the same:

```
RewriteRule ^/?.*?/[0-9]+_(.*)\.html?$ /search/result/?q=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Again, you can remove the `=301` bit if you don't want a permanent redirect.

---

EDIT:

In order to replace the query string's `_` character with `+` characters you'll definitely need to stick with mod_rewrite and need some extra rules for that:

```
# perform the initial rewrite, but don't redirect
RewriteRule ^/?.*?/[0-9]+_(.*)\.html?$ /search/result/?q=$1 [L]

# replace "_" with "+"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([^_]*)_(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?search/result/$ /search/result/?q=%1+%2 [L,NE]

# don't redirect until all "_" is replaced with "+"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([^_]+)$
RewriteRule ^/?search/result/$ /search/result?q=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Does that regex separate the two or more search terms with a + sign?  It looks to me as if it tacks female_rottweiler to the end instead of female+rottweiler

Comment: @Stofke No it doesn't replace the underscores with spaces (+ signs). That'll take an additional rule (see edit)

Comment: Do you need the second and third rule in place or would that third rule cover all.  Some urls will have three or more keywords.

Comment: @Stofke The third rule won't cover it all, all 3 work in conjunction to rewrite a URI to one with a query string, replace "_" with "+", then redirect the browser (respectively). The last rule only redirects the browser if the query string contains no "_" characters, which won't be enough.

Comment: @Stofke Also note that since the rewrite engine loops, you can have a URI like `/foo/123245_qwe_asd_zxc_123_456_789.htm` and because the second rule continues to get applied, the ultimate result is that you get redirected to `/search/result?q=qwe+asd+zxc+123+456+789`

Comment: Ah ok I see, it's a sort of loop?  How could one know this is a loop I really wonder who invented this complex syntax ;)  Thank you so much for your help this is very interesting stuff.